# What is the correct tense for giving a summary of a book or movie?

Tags: temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps, narration

In English I would typically state everything in the present tense, but does the same convention apply in French as well?

The sentence I am struggling with is: "The movie follows the story of (character), played by (actor's name), as he kills and maims his way towards justice."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present tense should be ok for your example.

> Ce film raconte l'histoire de (machin), interprété par (bidule), qui mange, joue, chante...